# Multiple forms in a template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Just wondering what is the most efficient way to pass these forms to a single template and validate them.

```
class AForm(ModelForm):
    #stuff here

class BForm(ModelForm):
    #stuff here 

class CForm(ModelForm):
    #stuff here
```

Comment: tamplate...lol read tampon

Comment: ideally class A will have methods/variables specific to it, class B to it, etc... you would not want to combine them unless they are doing the same thing, the same part of the whole, and/or utilize the same objects/variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from .forms import AForm, BForm, CForm

def some_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        a_form = AForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        b_form = BForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        c_form = CForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if a_form.is_valid():
            #do stuff...
        if b_form.is_valid():
            #do stuff...
        if c_form.is_valid():
            #do_stuff...
    else:
        a_form = AForm()
        b_form = BForm()
        c_form = CForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {'a_form': a_form, 'b_form': b_form, 'c_form': c_form})
    return render_to_response('page.html', variables)
```

Comment: msc i have been do it this way too with prefix='somethin'  in it so is this a right way to do things?